# Detect if device is in motion in Android

Tags: android

How to detect in Android if device is moving or at 1 place?

Actually I don't want to insert location when device is at 1 place.

I tried using Accelerometer & activity recognition. But it doesn't help. Any good example will be helpful.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Post links.

Comment: Can you specify what you take as a movement ?

Comment: @YounasBangash I'm using Location Manager to get the locations. Then I'm inserting the locations in db & displaying on map. Everything is working fine. But if device is at 1 place map is generating like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/2DCBt.png

Comment: @EugenPechanec I tried using http://www.javatpoint.com/android-sensor-example

Comment: @EugenPechanec this as well. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognition

Comment: @YounasBangash I tried using Fused Location API but locations were not that much accurate. Thats why I switched to Location Manager.

Comment: did you use getspeed ?

Comment: you mean... before insertion I should apply check if speed is more than 0.0?

Comment: Superb!!! Thanks a ton @YounasBangash... getSpeed() really worked. :)

Comment: if it work please accept answer and vote up so that it help other user

Comment: yeah done... Guys apply speed check if you don't want your map to look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2DCBt.png) .

Answer (score 1):

If new location is within - let's say - 100m of old location, don't add it to database.

```
private static final float SIGNIFICANT_DISTANCE = 100f;

public void onLocationChanged(final Location newLocation) {
    if (newLocation != null) {
        final Location oldLocation = ; // Get last location from DB / field.
        if (oldLocation == null ) {
            // If this is first measurement
            // Add to DB.
        } else if (oldLocation.distanceTo(newLocation) > SIGNIFICANT_DISTANCE) {
            // If user has moved significantly
            // Add to DB.
        } else {
            // If user hasn't moved significantly
            // Ignore it or implement some sort of precision refinement logic and update entry in DB.
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally you'll want to enable listening to location only when Activity Recognition reports the user is on the move.